# Shape within another shape (in different images) using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, connected-components

I'm attempting to implement a Connected Component Tree structure in openCV. after a series of thresholds from 0..255 with a certain interval i obtain a set of Photos - for in stance: 
[image: threshold 150]

[image: threshold 170]

is there a methodes to detect for each shape in the seconed image if it is contained within another shape in the first image?

Many Thanks!

Comment: If the shapes aren't moved then:
1. Compute number of white pixels on the first image
2. Add images with saturation
3. Compute the number of white pixels after addition
If the values are equal (before and after addition) then the second image is contained in the first image

Answer (score 0):

Take the image with the shape in question (2nd image), and remove all other shapes.  Then 'and' the image with the 1st image.  If the result is the same as the image with the single shape, it is contained.

Obviously this can be optimized to not go through the entire process for each shape.